# stoping ef-core to insert referenced record in to master table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have a setup as follows.

1. `Supermaster` has a collection of `Master`.
2. `Master` having FK reference to `Reference` PK Id
3. `Reference` table has readonly reference data.

In ef code when i load records from `Supermaster` table i add `reference` to each `Master` based on some condition.

on submission of `Supermaster` i expect `Supermaster` to be saved with all `Master` with reference to `Reference`.

But on `dbContext.SaveChanges()` EF tries to insert record to `Reference` and fails with PK constrain.

**What i have tried till now**

I have tried creating one to one relationship with foreign Key using Fluent API.

I have tried Detaching Entity before saving the context

`_context.Entry(programmingRecord.ProgrammingRecordParameters.Select(x=>x.ValidationRule)).State = EntityState.Detached;`

.

Here is code.

**Entity**

```cs
Public class Supermaster
{
    public virtual ICollection<Master> ProgrammingRecordParameters { get; set; }
}

   public class Reference
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


   public class Master
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DataGroup { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ValidationRuleId")]
        public Reference ValidationRule { get; set; }
        public int? ValidationRuleId { get; set; }
    }
```

**API**

```cs
    private void AddParameter(
            Supermaster rec,
            Master programmableParameter)
        {
            var param = new Master
            {                
                DataGroup = programmableParameter.DataGroup,
                ValidationRule = _context.References.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Description==programmableParameter.DataGroup
            };

            rec.ProgrammingRecordParameters.Add(param);
        }

        public IActionResult PostProgrammingRecord([FromBody] Master programmingRecord)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }


            var repo = new ProgrammingRepository(_context);
            _context.ProgrammingRecords.Add(programmingRecord);
                _context.SaveChanges();
       }
```

**Following is the Error stack**

```
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at RadioTMS.Web.Controllers.API.ProgrammingController.PostProgrammingRecord(ProgrammingRecord programmingRecord) in D:\TMS_Git_Repo\radio-tms\RadioTMS.Web\Controllers\API\ProgrammingController.cs:line 181
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ValidationRules' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Comment: What does `context.Entry(param.ValidationRule).State` return, before and after `rec.ProgrammingRecordParameters.Add(param);` ?

Comment: @Minijack - It reamins `Unchanged`

Comment: @SKDesai Your `AddParameter(programmableParameter)` method creates a new `param` internally, and doesn't change the raw `programmableParameter`. So when you invoke `_context.ProgrammingRecords.Add(programmingRecord);` later,  you're operating on the `programmingRecord` instead of the `param`. Because the `programmingRecord.ValidationRule` is not tracked, the EF-Core will try to insert/update the Database, which results in an exception.

Comment: @itminus - Ahh...i think this is the case. i think in this case i need to explicitly tell EF not to update Validation Rule before i save DBContext. Let me give it a go and i'll update...

Answer (score 0):

EF is trying to insert record in reference table because entity context does not have reference data loaded.You should get record of reference loaded in context before calling save changes.

Comment: `DBContext` has the reference data populated. I can confirm that as i am usnig these data on `AddParameter()` call.